# Powershell to refresh Excel with OLAP Query. Credential issues

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm rather new with PowerShell scripting so please be patient with me :)

I have multiple excel file with OLAP Query connections connecting to Power BI Datasets, following are the script;

```
 $libraryPath = "C:\Repos\AUSD\3.0\Test"  
 $excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application 
 $excel.Visible = $false
 # Give delay to open  
 Start-Sleep -s 3  
 $allExcelfiles = Get-ChildItem $libraryPath -recurse -include “*.xls*”  
 foreach ($file in $allExcelfiles)  
 {  
      $workbookpath = $file.fullname  
           Write-Host "Updating " $workbookpath  
           # Open the Excel file  
           $excelworkbook = $excel.workbooks.Open($workbookpath)  
           $connections = $excelworkbook.Connections  
           # This will Refresh All the pivot tables data.  
           $excelworkbook.RefreshAll()  
           # The following script lines will Save the file.  
           $excelworkbook.Save()  
           $excelworkbook.Close()
           Write-Host "Update Complete " $workbookpath  

      }  
 $excel.quit()
```

It is working fine if following options;
$excel.Visible is true

However this is going to be scheduled in the server and hopefully this could be done in the background, hence the $excel.Visible = $false

This causing the following error;

[image: Error 1 - Credentials needed]

[image: Error 2 - Credentials needed]

I suspect this is due to the Automatic sign in which happen when the Excel are open, due to its not being open, its failing the sign in process.

How do I bypass or rather set the credentials/permission right?

Comment: check permissions to database, I guess you are using a different user using the Scheduler.

Comment: Even if I force the User ID and Password into the connection string, it won't work either. But having <$excel.Visible = true> would work, but I'm looking for a way for the  refresh to happen without opening the Excel.